# Create loop like codeigniter in django

Tags: django, python-3.x, jinja2

Controller :

```
$data['all'] = SQL::get_data($this,tbl_menu,'*',array('parent_id'=>0),'urutan','',null)->result();
    foreach ($data['all'] as $all){
        $data['child'][$all->id] =  SQL::get_data($this,tbl_menu,'*',array('parent_id'=>$all->id),'urutan','',null)->result();
    }
```

in View :

```
<? $i = 1; foreach ($all as $a) { 
  $i++; foreach($child[$a->id] as $c ){ 
  }}?>
```

Working in view.py

```
for menu in headerData['resData']:
    headerData['child'] = {}
    headerData['child'][menu.id_menu] = SQL.objects.filter(parent_id=menu.id_menu)
```

in jinja HTML :

```
{% for res in resData %} 
 {{res.id_menu}} #is showing
{% for sub in child.id_menu %} 
{{sub.nama}} #not howing
{% endfor %} 
{% endfor %}
```

I want code in codeigniter like this 
How To Apply in Django ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
data = {}
data['all'] = MenuModel.objects.filter(parent=None)
for menu in data['all']:
    data['child'][menu.id] = MenuModel.objects.filter(parent_id=menu.id)
```

Comment: it's working but in html not show loop child look top questions @kangfend

Answer (score 1):

for in query object

```
for a in all:
     child[a]=<your sql command based on database>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean foreach equivalent in python, then you could use :

```
for variable in iterable
```

For example you want to access item from an array then use it as index, it would be something like :

```
for a in all:
    print(child[a])
```